# Android apps folder does not contain manifests folder in Android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have watched a tutorial movie which is made a project. But I have made a project by android studio which it does not have manifests folder and Androidmanifests.xml file. Why does not it have? How can I add them to my project?

Answer (score 3):

it will be at

```
app>src>main>AndroidManifest.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the general structure of an Android Studio project. The manifest will be inside the `manifests` folder inside your `app` module.

[image: Project Window]

You can change the project view from Android -> Project if you are more familiar with eclipse. You may be in a different view. Change it to Android to get the above project structure.

To Create a Manifest file Right Click -> New -> Other > Android Manifest.

[image]

PS: I am using Android Studio 1.5.1.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I just have java, test, recources, and gradle folder. How can I add manifests ?

Comment: @MohammadAliNematollahi Can you run the project? If yes Tap Shift key twice, type AndroidManifest and see if you can find the file.

Comment: No I cannot run it  Error:Unable to start the daemon process: could not reserve enough space for object heap.
Please assign more memory to Gradle in the project's gradle.properties file.
For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:
<em>org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m</em>
<a href="http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html">Read Gradle's configuration guide</a><br><a href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html">Read about Java's heap size</a>

Comment: Usually it adds on its own. You don't have to add it manually.

Comment: Ok you mean there is no way to add it manually? I should start the project again !?!

Comment: I have right click on app folder. When I go to new, there is no Other ! I can just see java class, module, ...  , XML